# Moderation using ANCOVA

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interaction, interpretation

I am performing a repeated measures ANCOVA with `Mood Scores` as the dependent variable, `Image Condition` as the independent variable, `BMI` as the covariate and `Time` as the random effect.

And I would like to find out if `BMI` moderates the changes in pre and post `mood scores` in all three `image conditions`. Hence, I would be looking for a 3-way interaction effect (`Time` × `Condition` × `BMI`) for this moderation effect.

However, I do not find any 3-way interaction effect, but a 2-way interaction effect (`BMI` × `Condition`) is found instead. 
Can anyone explain to me what this 2-way interaction effect implies? And is there any follow-up test that I need to do to clarify the 2-way interaction?
Thank you so much!